# nginx root document browser caching using expires /w try_files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

we have a dynamic front page. But it is not sooo dynamic - so we want it to be cached on the browser side for 10 minutes.

When I have the following location block it does not work

Probably because of the try_files

Problem is that when I inspect the root document (php code) that it is returned with code 200 as / (so no file name; just domain followed by a slash)

**question**: how do I cache the root document? (so only main webpage document in root)

```
 location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
       #expires 10m;
       }
```

Comment: Any PHP code will be processed by a different location. The `location /` block is the default location for static content. Put the `expires` statement in your PHP location block, or get your PHP script to return the correct headers itself.